# Convert SQL query to Active Record query in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (sec)
          id, sec
   FROM   tasks
   ORDER  BY sec, id DESC
   ) sub
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  4;
```

I am wondering if the above SQL query can be converted to an Active Record query. For now I am using `find_by_sql` as follows:

```
Task.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (sec) id, sec FROM tasks ORDER BY sec, id DESC ) sub ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4")
```

Comment: can you give us more information on your table schema?

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think you need any more info - not because I don't want to share it - but just because I really don't think you need any more info. There is a table called `tasks` (model `Task`) and there are two `integer` columns (`id` and `sec`). You can see both the table creation and the query in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06db6/2) - there is an additional function there, which you can ignore.

Comment: I was mainly trying to understand the type of the sec column, thanks for letting me know its an integer

Answer (score 0):

```
Task.select('t.*').from(Task.distinct(:sec).select(:id, :sec).group(:sec).order('sec, id desc'), :t).order('id desc').limit(4)
```

or just do it with group by only (distinct not needed)

```
Task.select('t.*').from(Task.select(:id, :sec).group(:sec).order('sec, id desc'), :t).order('id desc').limit(4)
```

This AR query will split into 2 sql queries, main and sub queries. Sub query will retrieve distinct records on :sec attribute value and main query will order them in descending ids and limit records to 4

Comment: FWIW, I much prefer the find_by_sql version

Comment: @JohnNaegle Myself too prefer connection.execute and find_by_sql.