# How to select unique values from a single column, with a default scope, returning multiple columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

In a rails application I need to return an ActiveRecord collection containing multiple columns, but only 1 column must be unique. There is a default scope which is not the unique value.

Default Scope

```
default_scope { order('executed_at DESC') }
```

Current query WITHOUT unique :terms.

```
Search.where(organization_id: @my_array_of_ids)
      .executed_after(from_date_time)
      .limit(100)
      .pluck(:terms)
```

executed_after(from_date_time) is a scope as well. How can I alter the above query to return unique terms without using the .uniq method? I want this to be a single SQL statement.

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913969/postgres-distinct-but-only-for-one-column

Answer (score 0):

I also found this:

[Convert SQL query to Active Record query in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945508/convert-sql-query-to-active-record-query-in-rails-4)

Notice the Model.distinct(:column)

EDIT:

I'd guess it is something like this, but I'd need more info:

```
Search.distinct(:terms).select(:executed_at)
.where(organization_id: @my_array_of_ids)
  .executed_after(from_date_time)
  .limit(100)
  .group(:executed_at)
```

Comment: This gives me the error `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "searches.executed_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` I think it has something to do with the default scope

Comment: That is an SQL error, you need to add the column to a group by clause with `.group(:executed_at)`

Comment: I've tried that, the problem is that executed_at is a time stamp with all unique results. I don't care if these are unique or not; only if the terms are unique.

Comment: But the executed_at column is in the select clause is that correct? In case it is in the select clause, despite it not being one of the distinct parameters, it must be in the group by clause, since it is all unique, it will just not group any records.

Comment: I believe the default scope makes it part of the select clause. `SELECT terms, executed_at GROUP BY terms, executed_at` will return all results given that executed at is a time stamp. I need a way around this

Comment: What precisely needs to be returned given the unique column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62537/discussion-between-marcelo-risoli-and-cheeseandpepper).